# What's the best way to implement different views for a website based on role?

Tags: asp.net, security, roles

In ASP.NET what's the best way to do the following:

1. Show certain controls based on your rights?
2. For a gridview control, how do you show certain columns based on your role?

I'm thinking for number 2, have the data come from a role specific view on the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of actually using roles to hide/show certain controls, I would suggest having another layer of permissions for each role and show/hide based on those instead.

That way you can redefine what permissions a role has and won't have to change your code.

Also, this allows you to make new roles in the future and just assign a set of permissions to the role.

As for controls, yes... I would just set the Visible property on the control based on the user.IsInRole("permissionname") value.

For grids I would do the same... set the Visibility of the columns to the IsInRole boolean value.

```
//Delete Icon Column
gridViewContacts.Columns[0].Visible = user.IsInRole("DeleteAnyContact");
```

I would make create your permissions in a very granular nature.. such as

- ViewAnyContact
- ViewOwnContact
- EditOwnContact
- EditAnyContact
- AddAnyContact
- DeleteOwnContact
- DeleteAnyContact
- Etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you're going the role-based route, ASP.NET (since version 2.0) has had a variety of membership controls available which might help in this scenario. Assuming (and this could well be a faulty assumption) that you're using the in-box membership provider, you can actually use the `LoginView` control to get #1 handled.

The way it works is that the `LoginView` can use `RoleGroups` and their associated `ContentTemplates` to customize the view for the user based on role. This works seamlessly with the in-box membership provider; I believe if you build your own membership provider based on Microsoft's technology it will also work. (I haven't done this latter step.)

Conceivably, you **could** use it for #2, but it'd wind up with duplicated code and effort, which isn't my personal preference. I think your choice of using role-specific SQL views to drive that table may be better than this option. (There are other options as well, of course, which may be better.)

I will second Elijah Manor's recommendation of using permissions instead of roles. Generally, that's my preference as well. (And I was surprised to discover that the membership provider technology didn't go to that level.) In any permission-centric scenario, though, you will essentially have to roll everything yourself. (I've done this, and while it's very flexible, the code to secure any given page can get hairy.)

EDIT: I apologize; I meant to include a link for the LoginView control. DotNetJunkies has a [tutorial](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/loginview.aspx) on it.